# Highlight unused vars in vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to highlight unused php-variables in vscode?

```
<?php
$foo = 'a';
$bar = 'b'; // I want the IDE mark this somehow

$foo = 'c';
?>
```

I have `"editor.showUnused": true` in the config file. Also, I tried a couple `intellisense` extensions, but it didn't help.

Comment: I'm afraid that Visual Studio Code is not a state of the art tool when it comes to PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least 2 possibilities :

- Use PHP mess detector (phpmd), there is an extension for VsCode : ecodes.vscode-phpmd.
  It will output warnings about unused variables, add indicators in the scrollbar and underline the line/variable in blue. You can remove every rules in config and keep only `unusedcode`
- Use Intelephense extension : bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client.
  It will color in grey unused variables

Comment: Currently, the PHP Intelephense extension marks unused code.

Answer (score 4):

I found another way to underline unused variables:

1. Open user settings vscode:

- Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- macOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

2. Add more line

   ```
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
     "editorUnnecessaryCode.border": "red",
   },
   ```

Comment: Using the built in settings menu (Ctrl+, or File > Preferences > Settings) you be able to open the settings file direcly and switch to the JSON view as well. Your mentioned setting does set the color for highlighting unused code but not necessarly enables it.

Comment: thank @Seth for your recommendation. By default the color in grey unused variables, it difficult to see and I always missed unused variables. Then I find another way to highlight unused variables so it is easier to check and I never miss unused variables again.
I can not find how to open the settings file and switch to JSON view (Ctrl+, or File > Preferences > Settings). I found another way to open settings.json: F1 -> type "open settings" -> choose "Open Settings (JSON)"